# Ruby Docs Mixin Example - Wrong number of Arguments

Tags: ruby

ruby-docs.org tutorial has [section on Modules](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) where the concept of Mixins are introduced.
The example given references the first argument as a string and prints it. But I see in the code that there is no receiver for the argument and execution does fail with `ArgumentError`

```
# Ruby module Mixin example.

module Debug
  def whoAmI?
    "#{self.type.name} (\##{self.id}): #{self.to_s}"
  end
end
class Phonograph
  include Debug
  # ...
end
class EightTrack
  include Debug
  # ...
end
ph = Phonograph.new("West End Blues")
et = EightTrack.new("Surrealistic Pillow")
ph.whoAmI? #»   "Phonograph (#537766170): West End Blues"
et.whoAmI? #»   "EightTrack (#537765860): Surrealistic Pillow"
```

My question is what is **proper** way to fix this code? Also, if someone can enlighten, how come the example in tutorial is wrong. Did anything change between the versions of ruby?

[tw-mbp13-skumaran ruby]$ ruby ruby23.rb 
ruby23.rb:16:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from ruby23.rb:16:in`new'
    from ruby23.rb:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `# ...` indicates several missing methods in the code. Try this: https://gist.github.com/3353490